# Token {contact.address_primary.street_number} - how to get it working

Tags: tokens, addresses

Have tried the `{contact.address_primary.street_number}` token for addresses (after discovering "Street Address Parsing" does not work for custom locales, see:  [1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34171/is-there-a-hook-for-address-parsing), [2](https://civicrm.org/extensions/street-format-parsing-dutch-format), [3](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21769) ). However it doesn't seem to be working even on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Any additional settings to alter somewhere to make it work or is this a bug?

[image: dmaster.demo.civicrm.org sample]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.